# Error While Running Kivy Application on Pydev

Tags: python, kivy

On python34 and Mingw compiler, While running `kivy` application, I am  facing this error. Can someone help me?

```
[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\Naver-Say\.kivy\logs\kivy_16-08-05_8.txt
[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.1
[INFO              ] [Python      ] v3.4.4 (v3.4.4:737efcadf5a6, Dec 20 2015, 19:28:18) [MSC v.1600 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 179 symbols loaded
[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sdl2 (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "D:\pythonData\kivyproject\kivyapp.py", line 4, in <module>
     from kivy.app import App
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 327, in <module>
     from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 219, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics import (
   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\kivy\graphics\__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
     from kivy.graphics.instructions import Callback, Canvas, CanvasBase, \
   File "kivy\graphics\vbo.pxd", line 7, in init kivy.graphics.instructions (kivy\graphics\instructions.c:14640)
   File "kivy\graphics\compiler.pxd", line 1, in init kivy.graphics.vbo (kivy\graphics\vbo.c:5482)
   File "kivy\graphics\shader.pxd", line 5, in init kivy.graphics.compiler (kivy\graphics\compiler.c:2983)
   File "kivy\graphics\texture.pxd", line 3, in init kivy.graphics.shader (kivy\graphics\shader.c:11990)
   File "kivy\graphics\fbo.pxd", line 5, in init kivy.graphics.texture (kivy\graphics\texture.c:31800)
   File "kivy\graphics\fbo.pyx", line 84, in init kivy.graphics.fbo (kivy\graphics\fbo.c:7683)
 ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified procedure could not be found.
```

Answer (score 0):

The error I believe is due to the dependencies not being installed. Here is the link to install it for windows https://kivy.org/docs/installation/installation-windows.html and you only need to install the top one.